# Tcpdump command - Linux - Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, command

I'm using the tcpdump command to capture traffic on the network interface eth0

**tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 > captureFile.txt**

in the shell appear the next message

tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
300 packets captured
302 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

How i can do message don't display in the command line???

Comment: I think you should be using `-w capturefile` instead. It's always better to have the pcap anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **2>/dev/null** at the end of the command line:

```
tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 > captureFile.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Tcpdump writes the message to standard error, and the > redirection works on standard out only.

If you want the message to appear in captureFile.txt, use:

```
tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 > captureFile.txt 2>&1
```

For more information on redirection, see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to suppress output of that command.

If you want to suppress:

- just messages (regular output), use:

  ```
  command > /dev/null
  ```
- just the errors (not recommended):

  ```
  command 2> /dev/null
  ```
- both errors and regular messages (again, not recommended):

  ```
  command > /dev/null 2>&1
  ```

This requires `tcpdump` to dump captured data to a file. You can do this by using the `-w` switch:

```
tcpdump -w capture.log
```